# Powerball in R: how to run faster?

Tags: r, sample

just for fun I'm running random numbers generator to get the powerball numbers + powerball. Code below. It's slow. And if I want to run it 1000 times to get stats - it will take forever.

Suggestions how to speed it up? Get rid of loop? 
Note: two random numbers are a must as powerball itself is a separate bucket.

Nothing serious here. Just having some fun. (1st run was successful at 175,226,831)

```
pwr_win = "4 8 19 27 34 10"
n = 500000000
win = 0

for (i in 1:n) { 
  if (i %% 100000 == 0) print(i)
  tmp = paste(paste(sort(sample(1:69,5)),collapse = " "),sample(1:26,1),collapse = " ")
  if (tmp == pwr_win) { 
    print(paste("win",i))
    win = i 
  }
}

print(win)
```

EDIT: the desired performance is - run the code to get the winning trial number (unlimited tries), say 290,000,000. Repeat many times to get the average to prove the 1/292M robability.

Comment: Why are you pasting them together?  I think comparing integers would be faster than doing all that pasting.

Comment: pasting for 5 numbers + powerball. paste might take some time indeed

Comment: Ideally. it would be good to get rid of paste and also get rid of 500M tries limit - I just didn't have time to think it thru carefully

Comment: If all you are doing is trying to match all numbers, I might do something like `identical(c(sort(sample(69, 5)), sample(21, 1)), as.integer(c(4, 8, 19, 27, 34, 10)))` for one run.  That gives you a logical output of whether you matched all numbers.  Then you can replicate it many many times.

Comment: @RichardScriven want to furnish it as a full blown answer to be upvoted and accepted? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be more efficient to use integers instead of comparing strings.  The below function `pbSim()` takes the winning numbers as input, runs one draw of the powerball, compares the two powerballs, and if they match it continues drawing the remaining numbers.  Otherwise it exits with a loss.  Then you can replicate that many times, and you will probably never win.

```
pbSim <- function(numbers) {
    if(!is.integer(numbers))
        numbers <- as.integer(numbers)
    if(identical(sample(21, 1), tail(numbers, 1L))) {
        draw <- sample(69, 5)
        identical(sort(draw), head(numbers, -1L))
    } else FALSE
}

pwr_win <- c(4, 8, 19, 27, 34, 10)
pbSim(pwr_win)
# [1] FALSE
replicate(10, pbSim(pwr_win))
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: So, you run it 500M times to get the 1st number. How would you optimize it to run N times where each time is the winner - to get average over ensemble

Comment: @AlexeyFerapontov - I may have misunderstood the question.   I am not exactly sure what you're after. Perhaps you want the other answer.

Comment: OK, here's what I was after: run code once - get trial number of an exact match + powerball. Repeat 1000000 times. The problem is that my code is too slow to run it even 3 times to get average.

Answer (score 3):

OK, getting the rules of the game down a bit. I'll change my answer, but the general approach is the same -- avoid iteration over single tickets.

I guess there are

```
tickets = choose(69, 5) * 26   # 292201338
```

possible tickets. One of them is the winner

```
winner = sample(tickets, 1)
```

You'd like to play multiple tickets, purchased with replacement `purchases = sample(tickets, tries, TRUE)`, and repeat until you have a winner

```
set.seed(123)
tries <- 100000000; n <- 0
repeat {
    purchases = sample(tickets, tries, TRUE)
    idx <- which(purchases == winner)
    if (length(idx))
        break
    n <- n + tries
    message(n)
}
```

The loop exits during the second iteration (a couple of seconds), when the first winner was the

```
> n + idx[1]
[1] 136801728
```

ticket purchased.

However, once the probability of winning is determined, then it's easy to generate the waiting time until a winner is purchased. Choosing the winner is a Poisson process, and the waiting time until first success is geometrically distributed. One can rapidly simulate waiting times to 1000 wins (i.e., 1000 winning tickets) with `rgeom(1000, 1 / tickets)`, but unfortunately this causes an integer overflow in R, so we calculate these by hand

```
wait = log(runif(1000)) / log(1 - 1 / tickets)) + 1
```

Comment: In Powerball, numbers cannot be repeated so "TRUE" must be "FALSE" in `sample`. Do you know how fast it runs until an average win?